# Hive. Over partition by vs where conditions

Tags: window-functions, hive

I have a table partitioned this way.

```
# Partition Information
# col_name              data_type 

year                    string
month                   string
day                     string
hour                    string
```

I want to run the query on a whole month. I understand that I could do

```
where day > 01 and day < 31
```

But the table is VERY big. I was told it would take too much time and that I should run it separately on every day. I thought about over partition by. Like

```
select col1, col2, sum(col3) over (partition by day)
from table
```

but I am not sure how this will work. Would the query work on every day successively. Would it be easier on the cluster? Would col1 and col2 be grouped automatically or would I need to add group by?

```
Table
col1 col2 col3 month date....
1    s    4    01    01
1    s    3    01    01
1    q    5    01    01
```

What I want in the result

```
col1 col2 col3 month date....
1    s    7    01    01
1    q    5    01    01
```

Comment: Please leave the performance consideration aside for a minute and simply describe what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: P.s. how big is "VERY big"?

Comment: @Dudu Updated the question. Every day holds around 200 GB of data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make use of the partitions -

Your query on the whole month should look something like this:

```
select      col1,col2,sum(col3),year,month,day
from        mytale
where       year  = '2017'
        and month = '02'
group by    col1,col2,year,month,day
```

Your query on a single day should look something like this:

```
select      col1,col2,sum(col3),year,month,day
from        mytale
where       year  = '2017'
        and month = '02'
        and day   = '01'
group by    col1,col2,year,month,day
```

Your query on a range of days should look something like this:

```
select      col1,col2,sum(col3),year,month,day
from        mytale
where       year  = '2017'
        and month = '02'
        and day between '01' and '07'
group by    col1,col2,year,month,day
```